# How to configure Spring Data REST to return the newly created entity as part of the body for a POST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Data REST to expose my JPA repositories as Web Services.

I'm testing each of these Web Services using RestTemplate. I want those tests to be integration tests... meaning that I'm executing each test while my application is running. I don't want to mock anything.

Now what I want to know is how to configure Spring Data REST to return the newly created entity as part of the body when sending an HTTP POST.

I've tried to set the appropriate flags in configuration class RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my configuration class :

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
        RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
        config.setBasePath("/sdr-api");                
        config.setReturnBodyOnCreate(Boolean.TRUE);
        config.setReturnBodyOnUpdate(Boolean.TRUE);        
        config.exposeIdsFor(Project.class);        
        config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);        
        return config;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a test I wanna be able to perform :

```
@Test
@SqlGroup({ @Sql(scripts = "/clear-data.sql", config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = TransactionMode.ISOLATED)) })
public void create() {
    final String PROJECT_NAME = "MY_PROJECT";

    Project project = new Project();
    project.setName(PROJECT_NAME);

    ResponseEntity<Project> response = restTemplate().postForEntity(getBaseUrl() + "projects", project, Project.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.CREATED));

    Project projectCreated = response.getBody();
    assertThat(projectCreated.getId(), notNullValue());
    assertThat(projectCreated.getCreatedBy(), notNullValue());
    assertThat(projectCreated.getCreatedDate(), notNullValue());
    assertThat(projectCreated.getLastModifiedBy(), notNullValue());
    assertThat(projectCreated.getLastModifiedDate(), notNullValue());
    assertThat(projectCreated.getName(), equalTo(PROJECT_NAME));
}
```

This test is failing on the following statement because the ID is null, as well as all the other properties...

```
assertThat(projectCreated.getId(), notNullValue());
```

Even when I try to call the WS using curl, it doesn't give the result I expect...

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{ "name" : "MY_PROJECT" }' http://localhost:8081/myproject/sdr-api/projects
```

It should return the newly created entity and it should return the result as application/json and NOT application/hal+json as specified in my configuration class...

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-Modified, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
ETag: "0"
Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2015 19:59:12 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8081/myproject/sdr-api/projects/4
Content-Type: application/hal+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 10 Nov 2015 19:59:12 GMT

{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/myproject/sdr-api/projects/4"
    },
    "project" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/myproject/sdr-api/projects/4{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea on what the problem may be?

I've tried many things over the last few hours... with Spring 2.4.0.RELEASE, I've tried using the `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` as suggested by

```
@Configuration
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class SpringDataRestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setBasePath("/sdr-api");
        config.setReturnBodyOnCreate(Boolean.TRUE);
        config.setReturnBodyOnUpdate(Boolean.TRUE);
        config.exposeIdsFor(Project.class);
        config.useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType(false);
        config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

But I'm still getting the same result... the code seems to be executed though as my SDR API is available under /sdr-api.

So I've decided to downgrade the version of Spring Data Rest to 2.3.2.RELEASE. I've modified my configuration class this way :

```
@Configuration
public class MySDRConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setBasePath("/sdr-api");
        config.setReturnBodyOnCreate(Boolean.TRUE);
        config.setReturnBodyOnUpdate(Boolean.TRUE);
        config.exposeIdsFor(Project.class);
        config.useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType(false);
        config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

And this time, it's working! The result I get is what I was expecting :

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-Modified, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
ETag: "0"
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Nov 2015 20:55:32 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8081/myproject/sdr-api/projects/3
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 12 Nov 2015 20:55:32 GMT

{
  "id" : 3,
  "createdBy" : "anonymousUser",
  "createdDate" : "2015-11-12T20:55:32.368Z",
  "lastModifiedBy" : "anonymousUser",
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2015-11-12T20:55:32.368Z",
  "name" : "TEST",
  "links" : [ ],
  "content" : [ ],
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8081/myproject/sdr-api/projects/3"
  }, {
    "rel" : "testPlans",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8081/myproject/sdr-api/projects/3/testPlans"
  } ]
}
```

Am I missing something with the newest version of Spring Data REST?

Comment: Try instead extending `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`, override `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config)` method and set your configuration there. I have not tried it personally, but that seems to be the way recommended by the documentation...

Comment: Try to set useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType to false in your RepositoryRestConfiguration.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt If I look at the Spring Data REST documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.configuration), it seems to recommend using `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`... where can I find the documentation regarding the `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` ?

Comment: @proactive-e I've already tried setting this flag to false and the output didn't change

Comment: You try to override the config method. But instead of that overwriting it you should override `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration)` which gets automatically called by the config method. However this is now deprecated and its [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.html#configureRepositoryRestConfiguration-org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration-) points to the configurer approach I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I've tried what you suggested, but without success... I've edited my post according to my latest findings.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring:

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.7.5</version>
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class QuizApplication implements ViewProvider {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuizApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return RepositoryRestConfigurer.withConfig(config -> config.exposeIdsFor(Question.class));
    }
}
```